# How to get the trigger the way logic wants ?

Tags: oracle, triggers

I am trying to create trigger which fires and store results in aud table when any new row has been updated or inserted in the source table. 
I am using below script to create that trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER abc.E_M_IU_T
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
ON abc.E_A_R_L_T
REFERENCING NEW AS New OLD AS Old
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
V_ID NUMBER;
BEGIN
SELECT MDM_SEQ_NBR.NEXTVAL INTO V_ID FROM dual;
IF 
UPDATING AND 
:Old.Row_Updater_Nam !='M_S_U' OR :Old.Row_Updater_Nam!='S_S_U' then
BEGIN 
            Insert Into abc.aud
                      ( MDM_IUD_SEQ_NBR
                       ,ENTITY_ID
                       ,ENTITY_TYPE_CD
                       ,DATA_CHANGE_CD
                       ,TABLE_NAME
                       ,PRIMARY_KEY_COL
                       ,SECONDARY_KEY_COL
                       ,PRIMARY_KEY_VAL
                       ,ROW_PROCESS_CD
                       ,ERROR_MSG
                       ,ROW_INSERT_DT
                       ,ROW_UPDATE_DT
                       ,ROW_UPDATER_NAM)
                Values ( V_ID
                       ,:Old.E_ID
                       ,:Old.E_CD
                       ,'C'
                       ,'E_A_R_L_T'
                       ,NULL
                       ,NULL
                       ,NULL
                       ,'N'
                       ,NULL
                       ,SYSDATE
                       ,NULL
                       ,'E_M_IU_T'); 
END; 
elsif INSERTING AND 
:New.Row_Updater_Nam !='M_S_U' OR  :New.Row_Updater_Nam !='S_S_U'  then
BEGIN 
            Insert Into abc.aud
                      ( MDM_IUD_SEQ_NBR
                       ,ENTITY_ID
                       ,ENTITY_TYPE_CD
                       ,DATA_CHANGE_CD
                       ,TABLE_NAME
                       ,PRIMARY_KEY_COL
                       ,SECONDARY_KEY_COL
                       ,PRIMARY_KEY_VAL
                       ,ROW_PROCESS_CD
                       ,ERROR_MSG
                       ,ROW_INSERT_DT
                       ,ROW_UPDATE_DT
                       ,ROW_UPDATER_NAM)
                Values ( V_ID
                       ,:New.E_ID
                       ,:New.E_CD
                       ,'C'
                       ,'E_A_R_L_T'
                       ,NULL
                       ,NULL
                       ,NULL
                       ,'N'
                       ,NULL
                       ,SYSDATE
                       ,NULL
                       ,'E_M_IU_T'); 

END; 
END IF;
END;
/
```

I am able to create the trigger successfully. But when I am inserting/updating any records in source table, it writes to aud table regardless of the value of row_updater_nam column. I have used != 'm_s_u' and != 's_s_u' in the trigger script, but it seems like it is ignoring it. 
Can anyone help me to get it resolved? 
If you feel my trigger script is not accurate, please advise as well.

Thank You

Comment: Use an AFTER trigger, not a BEFORE.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a simple mistake in the logical operators used. You have

```
IF UPDATING AND :Old.Row_Updater_Nam != 'M_S_U' OR :Old.Row_Updater_Nam != 'S_S_U' THEN
```

While you should be using `AND` instead of `OR`:

```
IF UPDATING AND :Old.Row_Updater_Nam != 'M_S_U' AND :Old.Row_Updater_Nam != 'S_S_U' THEN
```

The same goes for `INSERTING`. Is:

```
ELSIF INSERTING AND :New.Row_Updater_Nam != 'M_S_U' OR :New.Row_Updater_Nam !='S_S_U' THEN
```

Should be:

```
ELSIF INSERTING AND :New.Row_Updater_Nam != 'M_S_U' AND :New.Row_Updater_Nam !='S_S_U' THEN
```

I'm assumint that `ROW_UPDATER_NAM` column is not nullable. Otherwise you may have issues with those conditions, when it is `NULL`.

Comment: I tried using AND instead of OR, 
In that scenario, it is not inserting at all no matter what the value is for row_updater_nam column.

Comment: You would have to give us something more, to be able to test the problem. E.g. the full data structures (`CREATE TABLE`) of both tables (`abc.E_A_R_L_T` and `abc.aud`) and a sample `insert`/`update` statements on `abc.E_A_R_L_T`. Maybe even your sequence (`MDM_SEQ_NBR`) definition (esp. that it is not qualified with schema, while all other objects are).

Comment: CREATE TABLE abc.audit
(
  MDM_IUD_SEQ_NBR    NUMBER(20) NOT NULL,
  ENTITY_ID          VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) NOT NULL,
  ENTITY_TYPE_CD     VARCHAR2(5 BYTE) NOT NULL,
  DATA_CHANGE_CD     VARCHAR2(5 BYTE) NOT NULL,
  TABLE_NAME         VARCHAR2(100 BYTE) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY_KEY_COL   VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
  SECONDARY_KEY_COL  VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
  PRIMARY_KEY_VAL   VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
  ROW_PROCESS_CD    VARCHAR2(1 BYTE) NOT NULL,
  ERROR_MSG         VARCHAR2(256 BYTE),
  ROW_INSERT_DT     TIMESTAMP(6) NOT NULL,
  ROW_UPDATE_DT     TIMESTAMP(2),
  ROW_UPDATER_NAM   VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)
);

Comment: CREATE TABLE abc.E,A,R.L.T
(
  ENTITY_ID  VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)  NOT NULL,
  ENTITY_TYPE_CD   VARCHAR2(5 BYTE)   NOT NULL,
  ADDR_ROLE_CD  VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)  NOT NULL,
  ADDR_SEQ_NBR NUMBER(10)         NOT NULL,
  ADDR_TYPE_CD VARCHAR2(5 BYTE),
  EFFEC_DT DATE,
  INACTIVE_DT    DATE,
  ADDR_LINK_INACTIVE_RSN_CD  VARCHAR2(5 BYTE),
  PRIMARY_ADDR_IND           VARCHAR2(1 BYTE),
  PRIMARY_IND_LAST_CHG_DT    DATE,
  THIRD_PARTY_BILLING_IND    VARCHAR2(1 BYTE),
  ROW_INSERT_DT              DATE,
  ROW_UPDATE_DT              DATE,
  ROW_UPDATER_NAM            VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) ;

Comment: SELECT *
FROM abc.E.A.R.L.T
where addr_seq_nbr = '001'; 

UPDATE abc.E.A.R.L.T
SET ROW_UPDATER_NAM = 'M_S_U'
WHERE ADDR_SEQ_NBR = '001'
AND ADDR_TYPE_CD = 'POST'
and addr_role_cd = 'PHYSICAL'; 

SELECT *
FROM abc.audit
where entity_id = '994011355416' ; 

When I am updating ROW_UPDATER_NAM column as mentioned above, It is firing trigger but it should not because I have used row_updater_nam != 'M_S_U' or 'S_S_U'. 

Other than msu and ssu, for whatever value, it should update/insert new record in audit table by firing trigger. 

Hope this will help. 

Thank You

Comment: CREATE SEQUENCE abc..MDM_SEQ_NBR
  START WITH 1
  MAXVALUE 10000000000
  MINVALUE 1
  NOCYCLE
  CACHE 20
  NOORDER; 

this is the script for sequencer.